# Reindex the products after updating the products

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex

I have a updated or added a products through the cron file. Every time after updating the products i need to reindex the products, Is there any way to reindex products after cron run.

Comment: Why dont you try to do it through code in your cron file.

Comment: kindly try to find something on google before asking any question. There are lot of solutions available there.

Answer (score 1):

Add following code to your .sh file and set this sh file in to your cron tab

```
php /YOurMagentoDir/shell/indexer.php --reindexall
```

Answer (score 0):

**Either do as @Neo is suggesting.** Or `if you are adding product through any php script then you can try this as well`.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory
 */
protected $_indexerFactory;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_indexerCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexerCollectionFactory
){
   $this->_indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
   $this->_indexerCollectionFactory = $indexerCollectionFactory;
}

// you can call this function to do reindexing
public function reIndexing(){
   $indexerCollection = $this->_indexerCollectionFactory->create();
   $ids = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();
   foreach ($ids as $id) {
   $idx = $this->_indexerFactory->create()->load($id);
   $idx->reindexAll($id); // this reindexes all
   //$idx->reindexRow($id); // or you can use reindexRow according to your need
}
```

Comment: This is magento 2 answer and OP has asked for Magento1 solution

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala ohh thats even easier.. :P . However i didnt notice. Lets just keep the answer it may help others.

Comment: keep magento2 part but update your answer for magento1 as well so your post solve basic purpose of MagentoSE.